# Convert Regex match into string

Tags: julia

I have a `RegexMatch` object which I'd like to convert into a string:

```
mm = match(r"(?<=Info: ).+", "Info: Kim")
```

However, I can't figure out how to convert it into a string. The following does not work:

- `String(mm)`
- `convert(String, mm)`

How is this supposed to be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `.match` will convert the `match` object into a string.

`mm.match`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use capturing group and index:

```
julia> mm = match(r"((?<=Info: ).+)", "Info: Kim")
RegexMatch("Kim", 1="Kim")

julia> mm[1]
"Kim"
```